# Chef bootstrap giving 401 unauthorized

Tags: ubuntu, centos, chef, knife

I'm trying to bootstrap a new chef node by running:
`knife bootstrap <server ip> -x lewis -N gitlab --sudo`
But I get the following output:
`[Mon, 03 Sep 2012 14:45:17 +0000] INFO: *** Chef 10.12.0 ***

[Mon, 03 Sep 2012 14:45:17 +0000] INFO: Client key /etc/chef/client.pem is not present - registering

[Mon, 03 Sep 2012 14:45:17 +0000] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 401 Unauthorized: Failed to authenticate. Ensure that your client key is valid.

[Mon, 03 Sep 2012 14:45:17 +0000] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out

[Mon, 03 Sep 2012 14:45:17 +0000] FATAL: Net::HTTPServerException: 401 "Unauthorized"`

My chef server is running Ubuntu 12.04 x32 and the machine I'm trying to bootstrap is running CentOS 6.3 x64

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: check date and time on ypur chef server and client

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same problem and fixed it from this thread http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.chef.user/2718

either ssh into your potential client machine and remove the `/etc/chef/client.pem` or run this quicky

```
ssh -t name@new.client.net "sudo rm /etc/chef/client.pem"
```

Run `knife bootstrap` again and it should work.
You may have registered this machine already with another chef server.

Comment: I have the same error as the op, and there is no client.pem on the node.

Comment: Yeah, it actually says there is no client.pem in the error message. My answer was to another question... oops.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Common+Errors#CommonErrors-401Unauthorized(usingvalidatorAPIclient)

You need to delete validation.pem and restart chef-server, since it's broken by default in current ubuntu chef-server package.

Comment: Hi @OlgeYch , while we appreciate links to tutorials or outside sources we do ask that you include the summary of the page or process in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get knife-bootstrap working add entries to your `~/.chef/knife.rb` like this:

```
validation_client_name  "chef-validator"
validation_key          "#{ENV["HOME"]}/.chef/validation.pem"
```

and put a copy of the `/etc/chef/validation.pem` file from the Chef server copied in to `$HOME/.chef/validation.pem`.

If you don't like knife-bootstrap there are a number of other ways of setting this up automatically

- create an OS image e.g a custom AMI with the validation file already in place
- use the cloud-init package that is part of Ubuntu to seed the image with the validation file

I've used cloud-init moderately successfully in the past, but it has its quirks.

Comment: Hmm, i removed everything the the `/etc/chef` directory and tried running the command again and still got the same error

Comment: Hi - sorry I misread your question slightly so I've rewritten the answer.  Give it a try now.

Comment: Nope, still not having any luck, same error again. Just to clarify, the error above is coming from the node I'm trying to bootstrap. Am I supposed to be doing this in the node or the chef server? (I've tried both)

Comment: @loddy1234 The node. You had it right.